# C# Sending cookie in an HttpWebRequest which is redirected

Tags: c#, api, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm looking for a way to work with an API which requires login, and then redirects to another URL.
The thing is that so far I've only come up with a way to make 2 Http Requests for each action I want to do: first, get cookie with AllowRedirect=false, then get the actual URI and do a second request with the cookie:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sUrl);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

string redirectedUrl = response.Headers["Location"];
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectedUrl))
{
    redirectedUrl = "http://www.ApiUrlComesHere.com/" + redirectedUrl;
    HttpWebRequest authenticatedRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(redirectedUrl);
    authenticatedRequest.Headers["Cookie"] = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];        
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

It seems terribly inefficient. Is there another way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems terribly inefficient.

Why?

In the end this is all `HttpWebRequest`, with `AllowAutoRedirect true` is going to do.

Comment: OK, and code-wise, isn't there a better way to implement this?

Comment: @Nir: not particularly (since you are not setting anything else for the original request).

Answer (score 1):

```
public String Post(String url, IDictionary<String, String> data)
    {
        String requestData = String.Join("&", data.Select(x => String.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x.Key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x.Value))));

        Byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        while (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
        {
            response.Close();

            String location = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.Location];

            request = WebRequest.Create(location) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

            response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }

        String responseData = this.Read(response.GetResponseStream());

        response.Close();

        return (responseData);
    }
```